# Orca does not seem to read most screen elements on my system

Tags: 18.04, accessibility, orca

I have fired up orca for the first time, and it seems to only read the titles of windows and tabs, or sometimes the first element on the window, but not anything else on the window.

When I go into its setup GUI (`orca -s` on the terminal) it does read aloud what the mouse is over inside that specific window belonging to orca itself, and it does read aloud things like window names on the application switcher.

But how does one make it read what's under the mouse position outside of its own setup GUI window? Would you suggest upgrading orca or other components? Windows I have tried: terminal window, Google Chrome, the Atom editor.

My orca version: 3.28.0

I'm actually using orca for a proof of concept of how well can an application based on GTK's Accessibility Toolkit (ATK) or GNOME Accessbility Implementation Library read windows' text content. If you know another project taking a good aim at that, I am happy to learn of that as well.